# Parallax "scrolling" only through navigation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, css, parallax

Since I'm still new to Javascript/Jquery/HTML5/CSS3, I thought I'd ask a question for all you much more experienced programmers out there.

I'm kind of stuck at the beginning of my program logic. I want to do a website with a parallax "scrolling" effect, however the effect should only take place when the user clicks navigation buttons on the edges of the screen.

The layout of the website will be like this:

```
 O
OXO
 O
```

The "O"'s are the content divs, "X" is the "home" page (point of origin). If the user clicks the arrow at the top of the screen (from point of origin), the page will scroll up. Same goes for any of the other directions. I'm wanting one giant photo of the establishment in the background that shifts it's position based on the specific content div they "scroll" to, using the parallax effect.

I've been racking my brain for two days trying to figure out where to start with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I need to be more specific about something. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at and considered the various JavaScript or jQuery based [**parallax plugins**](http://www.google.com/search?q=parallax+plugins) that are out there? I would start with a parallax engine that matches your needs. [**Stellar.js**](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) for example, allows for horizontal parallax effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have looked at many parallax plugins as I'm more or less wanting to do this in Jquery since other parts of my content will use Jquery.

Those plugins don't quite do what I need to do, or I don't have any idea on how I would implement them to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The home page content is in the middle of the parallax experience.

For this reason, you will need a parallax plugin that can handle both vertical and horizontal parallax effects to allow proper navigation in your webpage.

**Consider:** [**Scrolling Parallax Plugin for jQuery**](http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/examples/multi-directional-parallax)

The above parallax demo page allows you to scroll both directions.

Here's the method/approach I would take using this plugin.

**1.** Design your website with horizontal and vertical content as required. Layout example:

```
OOO     Here, the top of the webpage is content about the "starting" point.
OXO     Next, you have content on the sides of the "starting" point as shown.
OOO     Finally, content is below the "starting" point to complete the webpage.
```

**2.** Since the webpage visitor will see the very top of the webpage which is not desired, use `jQuery.scrollTo()` Plugin to set the "starting" point on page load.

**3.** Use a plugin or method that will allow 4 transparent arrow "div's" that are at each **viewport side in "fixed" position**. When clicking (***or hovering***) with the mouse, this will simulate scrollbar movement and the parallax webpage plugin will react accordingly. Example of layout (note outer navigation is semi-transparent):

```
UUUUU     Webpage top-content is here plus the overlay arrow for UP Navigation.
LOOOR     LEFT and RIGHT Navigation arrows are seen on top of more "top" content.
LOXOR     The center starting point will show the "fixed" Navigation arrows.
LOOOR     LEFT and RIGHT Navigation arrows are seen below the "starting" point.
DDDDD     Bottom-content is here plus the overlay arrow for DOWN Navigation.
```

The most difficult part of the webpage is to have enough "filler-content" that occupies the top and sides of the "starting" point. But if that "filler-content" is a thumbnail gallery, then this particular parallax page would look really nice (and unusual!).

Comment: Fantastic! You've sparked my brain and now I think I know where to start. Sub-question: How would I bind whichever parallax  plug-in I use to a onClick event instead of a scroll event? Would I have to dig through all the library code and replace scroll events?

Comment: Let's take a step back and dis-regard `.scrollTo()` as the choice. The O's along with "starting" point X should be all **separate webpages**, not ***div containers***. That is very important so that "starting" point X occupies the browsers viewport no matter the size of the browser window. Only when clicking a Navigation arrow (Up, Down, Left, or Right) does the "new page" (aka a "O" content page) scroll into view. Since each webpage is created with a parallax method, all animations occur automatically. The scroll script in this case is [**jQuery Ascensor**](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/#/house0)

Comment: This is much better actually... Especially since what I'm wanting to do is disable user scrolling (by mouse wheel, scroll bar, and/or trackpad) and only bind "scroll" movement to navigation buttons

Comment: Hey arttronics! The jQuery Ascensor plug-in uses divs and scrollTo()... How would I do the other method of loading separate webpages?

Comment: Configure each div to use a full iframe. Remember iframes follow the Same Origin Policy rules for domains, and some websites... even www.google.com will not allow to be iframed. Reference [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwe7y/)